# Посчитать количество элементов в массиве

Tags: php, битрикс

Всем привет, есть массив вида:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 2033
            [~ID] => 2033
            [NAME] => Заказ блюда
            [~NAME] => Заказ блюда
            [DATE_ACTIVE_FROM] => 
            [~DATE_ACTIVE_FROM] => 
            [PROPERTY_BLUDO_VALUE] => test1
            [~PROPERTY_BLUDO_VALUE] => test1
            [PROPERTY_BLUDO_VALUE_ID] => 13508
            [~PROPERTY_BLUDO_VALUE_ID] => 13508
            [CREATED_DATE] => 2020.04.07
            [~CREATED_DATE] => 2020.04.07
            [PROPERTY_TIME_VALUE] => 10:00
            [~PROPERTY_TIME_VALUE] => 10:00
            [PROPERTY_TIME_VALUE_ID] => 13507
            [~PROPERTY_TIME_VALUE_ID] => 13507
            [PROPERTY_CATEGORY_VALUE] => Завтрак
            [~PROPERTY_CATEGORY_VALUE] => Завтрак
            [PROPERTY_CATEGORY_VALUE_ID] => 13509
            [~PROPERTY_CATEGORY_VALUE_ID] => 13509
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 2034
            [~ID] => 2034
            [NAME] => Заказ блюда
            [~NAME] => Заказ блюда
            [DATE_ACTIVE_FROM] => 
            [~DATE_ACTIVE_FROM] => 
            [PROPERTY_BLUDO_VALUE] => test2
            [~PROPERTY_BLUDO_VALUE] => test2
            [PROPERTY_BLUDO_VALUE_ID] => 13512
            [~PROPERTY_BLUDO_VALUE_ID] => 13512
            [CREATED_DATE] => 2020.04.07
            [~CREATED_DATE] => 2020.04.07
            [PROPERTY_TIME_VALUE] => 10:00
            [~PROPERTY_TIME_VALUE] => 10:00
            [PROPERTY_TIME_VALUE_ID] => 13511
            [~PROPERTY_TIME_VALUE_ID] => 13511
            [PROPERTY_CATEGORY_VALUE] => Завтрак
            [~PROPERTY_CATEGORY_VALUE] => Завтрак
            [PROPERTY_CATEGORY_VALUE_ID] => 13513
            [~PROPERTY_CATEGORY_VALUE_ID] => 13513
        )
...
)
```

Нужно посчитать количество элементов [PROPERTY_BLUDO_VALUE] => test2. Например, что бы результат был: test2 - 2 шт.

Comment: Уточните, пожалуйста, Ваш вопрос. Не совсем понятно какого результата хотите добиться. Не просто же получить значение из `[PROPERTY_BLUDO_VALUE]` и `[~PROPERTY_BLUDO_VALUE]` и сравнить их.

Answer (score -2):

Решено:

```
$count = array_count_values(array_column($breakfest, 'PROPERTY_BLUDO_VALUE'));
```

Comment: Зачем писать свой вопрос сразу на несколько форумов а потом переписывать ответ с одного на дургой?